# Query works in GraphiQL but returns empty array in Actual Code while using React Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a simple query like this

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT = gql`
  query getTodosByProduct(
    $id: ID!
    $completed: Boolean = false
    $limit: Int = 100
  ) {
    product(id: $id) {
      hashtag
      todos(completed: $completed, limit: $limit) {
        body
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

In GraphiQL, it returns results like -

```
{
  "data": {
    "product": {
      "todos": [
        {
          "body": "Remove Custom Font from Tweet #a2k",
          "product": {
            "id": "1439"
          },
          "__typename": "Todo"
        },
        {
          "body": "Make Site a PWA #a2k",
          "product": {
            "id": "1439"
          },
          "__typename": "Todo"
        }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But while using React Apollo's Query component, it returns the `hashtag` properly but returns `todos` as an empty array [] & I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the query.

If I fetch additional parameters from the query outside of `todos` then it returns them properly but only `todos` returns empty array `[]`.

I am requesting it like -

```
<Query
      query={GET_TODOS_BY_PRODUCT}
      variables={{ id: state.get("selectedProduct.id") }}
    >
      {({ data: { product } }) => {
        return <Main todos={product.todos} hashtag={product.hashtag} />;
      }}
</Query>
```

And I can't seem to figure out why something's wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: you're not passing `$completed, $limit` to  `<Query />` component

Comment: it uses default values

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have any results for `completed=false`?

Comment: No as I said I get results in GraphiQL & its the same query copy-pasted which means it uses `completed=false` in GraphiQL itself

Comment: Ohh hell you are right. Idk how it is showing in GraphiQL then. Its not my API. Thank you @dkulkarni

Comment: Ace! You're welcome. I'm not sure what your query on Graphiql is exactly but it is very likely your query in graphiql is different to the one defined with Apollo :)

Comment: Again you are right & damn you are fast. Thank you I was trying to figure this out for 2 hours 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dkulkarni I found the solution. In my GraphiQL, `completed` was `true` & in Apollo, I didn't set it up so it was `false`.

And my product didn't have any `completed` equal to `false` so it was messing up.

Thanks again @dkulkarni I wasted 2 hours for this thing